# appropriate and polite response to "Thank you"

Tags: politeness

The examiner asks for checking the identification of the student, then returns it back and says "Thank you".

What is the appropriate and polite response the student should give?

Comment: What about "No problem."?

Comment: It's my pleasure.

Comment: *No problem* is often said but it is less formal and not quite as polite as "You're welcome". *No problem* is likely an informal shortening of something like: "It was no trouble at all."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

“Yes, sir” or “Yes, ma'am” or  “Certainly” seem to me as among the few appropriate responses possible if the examiner is performing a solemn and official required duty.

Replies like “Not at all”, “Don’t mention it”, “No problem”, and “Anytime” make light of the examiner's duty.
“Thank you”, although often suitable as a response to someone just doing their job properly, seems servile in this case.  “You’re welcome” runs the risk of seeming insincere as a response to the affront or bother of having one's identification checked.

Answer (score 2):

There are several cordial options you can use, including: "Not at all," "Don't mention it," "No problem," or "Anytime." You could also respond with "Thank you," since the person also did you a service.

Lastly, there is no need of responding to "Thank you" by words, but sometimes a simple smile or courteous nod can work just as well. This is especialy true if you are in a long line.

You can read more interesting opinions about this topic [here](http://www.hindu.com/edu/2009/10/26/stories/2009102650850300.htm), [here](http://www.englishforums.com/English/ResponseToThankYou/bbblkq/post.htm) [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=102444), and [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2516/how-do-native-english-speakers-respond-to-thank-you) (that last one links to an ELU question).